# Assign link to bar in plotly barchart?

Tags: python, hyperlink, plotly, bar-chart

I have managed to create a lovely barchart displaying the quantity of publications over a range of 33 years. It is based on a larger dataframe that holds all the information about all the publications, but the barchart is only supposed to display the quantity of publications per year. Therefore, I cereated a subset as a pandas.series that just contains the years and the value_counts of those years and am plotting the chart from there - it works well. My code for this looks like this:

```
data1 = data[data['Year'].notna()]
data1 = data1.astype({'Year':'int'})
data1 = data1[(data1['Year'] >= 1900) & (data1['Year'] <= 2100)]

s = data1['Year'].value_counts()[:33].sort_index()

fig = px.bar(s, labels={'index':'Jahr', 'value':'Anzahl'}, color='value', height=500)
fig.show()
```

Now what I want to do is basically add a link to each bar in this barchart that prompts a search for said year. However, I cannot figure out how and where to add those links to the code. I tried following [the solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67956537/how-do-you-add-a-clickable-link-to-each-bar-graph-using-plotly-express-in-python), but since it's based on a dataframe instead of series and also assigns the value instead of using the value_counts, I am struggling to adapt it properly.

EDIT: I've changed things a bit now created another dataframe that has the year, count and the corresponding url in it. I could use this it it's easier, but so far I still haven't managed to get the links attached to the individual bars. I've attempted the code below which still renders a plot, but shows no bars anymore and just all the years on top of each other in the middle of an otherwise emtpy square...?

```
for r in test.iterrows():
    fig.add_annotation(
        {
            #"x": r[1]["years"],
            #"y": r[1]["count"],
            "text": r[1]["url"],
        }
    )

fig.update()
```

EDIT: I have now found a solution that annotates the different bars and includes a link. However, the link is now on top of the bars and it all looks pretty ugly. Is there a better way of doing this, and, is there a way to hide the text and to basically have the whole bar clickable? Or is this not possible?

Here's the code I'm using now, if there's a better way of doing this, I'd be happy to learn:

```
fig2 = px.bar(test, x="years", y = "count", labels={'years':'Jahr', 'count':'Anzahl'}, color='count', height=500)

update = (len(test["years"]))

for i in range (0,update):     
    fig2.add_annotation(
            
                x= test["years"].values[i],
                textangle = 90,
                text = f"""<a href="{test["url"].values[i]}" target="_blank">{test["url"].values[i]}</a>""",
                visible=True,
    
            )
fig2.update_layout()
fig2.update_traces(textposition='inside')
fig2.show()
```

Comment: The following code will help you determine the cause of the error by checking the contents of the loop process. `for i,row in test.iterrows():print(i,row)`

Comment: Thank you - I've tried to understand this better and have now altered the code and can now see the graph with the bars (yeah!) as well as one annotation for the first element (double yeah!). The above suggested r[1]["years"] etc. doesn't work and always produces the error "String indices must be integer", so I changed these to test["years"].values[1], but that only annotates the first element (unsurprisingly). Linking it to the loop with r doesn't work as well, and I am a bit lost again. Any further suggestions on how to address those elements properly?